# Ajax request with chrome's cors plugin

Tags: extjs, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to make a cors ajax request to users/login to authenticate the user and send back a JWT token. The options request returns 200, whereas the post request returns 403 forbidden with 'Missing CSRF token cookie' error. I'm using chrome's cors plugin.  On my UsersController.php inside its initialize function i have  `$this->Auth->allow(['login']);`

cakephp server on localhost:8765 with 'cake server', and extjs server started on http://localhost:1841/ with 'sencha app watch'

LoginController.js

```
onLoginClick: function() {
        this.getView().mask('Effettuando il login..');
        var data = this.getView().down('form').getValues();
        App.security.Firewall.login(data.username, data.password).then(function() {
            this.getView().destroy();

            Ext.create({
                xtype: 'app-main'
            });
            this.getView().unmask();
        }.bind(this), function(data) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Errore', data.message || 'Impossibile eseguire il login in questo momento.');
        });
    }
```

Firewall.js

```
 login: function(username, password) {
        var deferred = new Ext.Deferred();
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://localhost:8765/users/login',
            method: 'POST',
            params: {
                'username': username,
                'password': password
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (data.token) {
                    App.security.TokenStorage.save(data.token);

                    deferred.resolve(data, response);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject(data, response);
                }
            },

            failure: function (response) {
                var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                App.security.TokenStorage.clear();

                deferred.reject(data, response);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

This is how i loaded the JWT Auth plugin

```
 $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'storage' => 'Memory',
            'authenticate' => [
                'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                    'userModel' => 'Users',
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'id'
                    ],

                    'parameter' => 'token',

                    // Boolean indicating whether the "sub" claim of JWT payload
                    // should be used to query the Users model and get user info.
                    // If set to `false` JWT's payload is directly returned.
                    'queryDatasource' => true,
                ]
            ],

            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false,
            'checkAuthIn' => 'Controller.initialize',

            // If you don't have a login action in your application set
            // 'loginAction' to false to prevent getting a MissingRouteException.
            'loginAction' => [
              'controller' => 'Users',
              'action' => 'login',
          ],
        ]);
```

and finally this is the user route

```
Router::scope('/users', function ($routes) {
    $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Users');    
});
```

'options' network tab:

GENERAL

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8765/users/login
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8765
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 14:44:03 +0000
Host: localhost:8765
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.26
```

REQUEST HEADERS

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:1841
Referer: http://localhost:1841/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
```

'post' network tab:

GENERAL

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8765/users/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: [::1]:8765
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 03 Jul 2019 14:44:08 +0000
Host: localhost:8765
X-DEBUGKIT-ID: 6d9d2319-d3a6-4022-a877-fb404d639081
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.26
```

REQUEST HEADERS

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:1841
Referer: http://localhost:1841/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

I just want to authenticate the user which is trying to login and send back to the client its JWT token. At the moment the request doesn't even 'reach' the login function. It's the first time that I try to make a login system

Comment: It looks like you have the CSRF middleware enabled (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-middleware)? That's what is throwing that error, you need to include the `X-CSRF-Token` in your AJAX requests, see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests

Comment: @ahoffner thanks for answering,but the problem is that i don't have the CSRF token at the moment of login, shouldn't it be generated after the login success? I probably didn't explain in well from the start, my bad.. Cake is blocking me before the request even reaches the login function

Comment: No, if the CSRF token would be generated _after_ sending data, then it would be useless, as its purpose is to be used for determining whether accepting POST data is allowed in the first place. If your API needs CSRF protection, then you need to issue a GET request first, and obtain the CSRF token from the response.

Comment: I ended up disabling the CSRF middleware completly, as i've read that in my case a JWT authentication is enough. Thanks for the time and the explanation tho